# Como funciona o sistema de cache do React-Native?

Tags: jquery, react-native

É o seguinte, criei um sistema que usa alguns componentes `Image` e carregam as imagens da internet.

Só que eu quero que as imagens apareçam mesmo quando o sistema está offline.

Percebi que existe um cache das imagens quando eu as acesso, e quando abro o app offline, muitas delas estão carregadas.

Quero saber como devo fazer para que todas as imagens fiquem no cache e também se existe um limite de tempo em que elas ficam armazenadas lá.

Aguardo.

Answer (score 1):

Salve, Ítalo.

utilize essa módulo https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image, ele vai te ajudar com o cache.

Emiliano